# How to add an ActionFilter to a non MVC project?

Tags: .net-4.0, action-filter

I have several projects written in **f/x4.0** that are **not** MVC.  No web involved.  In fact, one is a Windows Service, another is a set of Libraries used for either Win Forms or Command Line processing.  Now, in MVC3 you can do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RivWorks.FeedHandler.Library
{
    class AttributeLogsRequest : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
    {
        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            // do something here...
        }

        void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is add an ActionFilter to a Method or Class definition and the above 2 calls will happen automatically:

```
[AttributeLogsRequest]
public class MyController
{
    ...
}
```

My question is:  Is there anything else other than *ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter* I can use to create non-MVC dependant Filters for my code?  *ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter* provides information that is very MVC centric like ControllerName, Action, HttpContext, etc.  THere must be a simpler way to create a simple filter for cross-cutting concerns.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look like you need some AOP library to do this.

There are a lot of them out there. You can try 1 of the followings:

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/)

[Spring AOP](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop.html)

[Unity Policy Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511729.aspx)